# Blogger: Added Javascript but no result came out

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, blogger

First I edited my Blogger Template HTML.

I added the following script in the footer-1 section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtn');
copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextarea');
  copyTextarea.select();
});
var copyTextareaBtnb = document.querySelector('.js-textareacopybtnb');
copyTextareaBtnb.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('.js-copytextareab');
  copyTextarea.select();
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Next I added a blog with the following HTML:

```
<textarea class="js-copytextarea">text needed to copy</textarea>    
<button class="js-textareacopybtn">
<img src="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/images/clippy.svg" width="13" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
<textarea class="js-copytextareab">text 2 needed to copy</textarea>    
<button class="js-textareacopybtnb">
<img src="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/images/clippy.svg" width="13" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
```

Then I clicked on the first and then second button, nothing is copied.

Comment: `I added the following script in the <head> tag:` - there's your problem ... `copyTextareaBtn` will be undefined, as the button hasn't been rendered yet - you should see errors in your developer tools console which would've been useful information in the question

Comment: which is as I said, because you're running the javascript before the page is loaded

Comment: I solved the first problem. My second problem is how to make it double. I changed the variables, it just made it worse like the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="js-copytextarea" id="1" readonly="" style="font-family: courier;">TTTEXTTT</textarea><button class="js-textareacopybtn" data-id="1">CCCOPYYY</button>
<script>
$('.js-textareacopybtn').on('click', function(event) {
  var copyTextarea = $(this).data('id');
  $('#' + copyTextarea)[0].select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place all your code in one place (`<div>`, for example, or HTML widget).
And for scripts in Blogger use this structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
your js code here
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include jQuery for JavaScript. put this code before `<head/>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```