# jQuery - copy text when hovering <textarea>

Tags: jquery, copy, textarea

I am able to copy text in `<textarea>` in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189789/blogger-added-javascript-but-no-result-came-out#answer-40826754). But after I simplify that code to the following one:

```js
$('textarea').mouseout(function(){
  $('textarea').blur();
});

$('textarea').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).focus();
  $(this).select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

```css
textarea {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 17.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
BLABLABLA<textarea>Hover me, I am special!</textarea>BLABLABLA<br/>
<input placeholder="Paste me here!"></input>
```

I can select the text in that `<textarea>` but not copy the text. I tried:

1. `$(this)[0].execCommand('copy');`
2. `$(this).execCommand('copy');`
3. `this.execCommand('copy');`
4. `document.execCommand('copy');`

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, wow – what a bad idea. I really hope that this is not possible. Just imagine, you get something copied into the clipboard each time you accidentally move the mouse over an advertisement. I would like to know what is in the clipboard and what am I going to paste in this e-mail to the client.

Comment: I am posting long codes and it is frustrating for people to `ctrl`+`a` and `ctrl`+`c` everytime or to click a `click to copy to clipboard` button.

Comment: Related: [can't use document.execCommand('copy') with input type file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099600/cant-use-document-execcommandcopy-with-input-type-file).

Comment: Also, [cannot get document.execCommand to work properly with copying text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171088/cannot-get-document-execcommand-to-work-properly-with-copying-text).

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, there seems to be something in the browser implementations (tested using Blink 537.36) that handles the copy command differently, based on the kind of invocation. If I use a `click` event, the content will get copied. But the content is not copied, if I try this with a `mouseover` event.

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('copy-test');

var copyHandler = function(event) {
    event.target.select();
    var status = document.execCommand('copy', false);
    console.log( status ); // Only for testing
};

ta.addEventListener('mouseover', copyHandler);

ta.addEventListener('click', copyHandler);
```

```html
<textarea id="copy-test">Hello World!</textarea>
```

Comment: The reason may be one of the browser securiy measures that @feeela you said: user doesn' t know what is being copied when hovering ads accidentally, so without a click by user voluntarily, it is impossible to perform 'copy text when hovering `<whatever-tag>`' for now.

Answer (score -1):

If you made this you will need to click on textarea to copy:

```
$('textarea').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).focus(function(){
    $(this).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it still didn't work – even if I execute `focus()` and `select()` subsequently on the textarea.

Comment: This is working for me if I click on textbox. I think this could be browser related problem as @feeela said. Update: It is not working in Konqueror.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/kqxw80x3/4/

Here is a working copy of what you're trying to accomplish. Instead of `mouseover` try `hover`.

Comment: This is not working example. Problem is in copying not alerting.

Comment: This is still wrong. He wants to copy text to clippboard not to other element.